# Retrieve / navigate to a view that expects a struct?

Tags: struct, swiftui

I'm using NavigationLink to navigate to another view, and within a completely different view, I need to navigate back to the "original" view.

My book struct looks like this:

```
struct Book: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var author: String
    var chapters: Int
    var group: String
    var name: String

}
```

The book view expects a `book`, as such: `destination: BookView(book: book),`

However, in my "foreign" view that I wish to navigate back from (`ChapterView`), all I got are the "loose" values of the book - `book_id, author, chapters` etc.

How do I "transform"/cast these loose values back into a book struct so I can pass that along in the view?

I can't simply go `destination: BookView(book.id: book_id, author: chapter_author)` if you know what I mean.

Comment: Can you make the struct? `destination: BookView(Book(id: ...))`

Comment: Just getting a bunch of 
`value of type 'Int' has no member 'book_id'`.
`destination: BookView(verse: Book(id: verse.book_id, book_name: verse.book_name)...`